# Problema comprobar cookies en PHP y Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

Tengo una pagina de inicio de sesión y una pagina principal. mi pagina de inicio de sesión es mi index y es ahí donde uno inicia sesión con las credenciales, pero resulta en un error. El tema es que yo ingreso con las credenciales correctas, pero luego, una vez que estoy en la pagina principal, esta me redirige nuevamente al inicio de sesión.

Mi pagina principal esta linkeada a un JS que es el siguiente. En este script las cookies se comprueban para ver si existen y que valor tienen, en caso de que no existan, retorna al usuario al inicio de sesion:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
    const value = document.cookie;
    const parts = value.split('; ' + name + '=');
    
    if (parts.length === 2) {
        return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
    }
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    if (getCookie('sesion') === '1') {
        alert("Log in autorizado"); // te mantiene en la pagina actual
    } else {
        window.location.replace("https://pruebastrant.store/index.html");
    }
});
```

Y esta es la forma en la que setee las cookies en mi php:

```php
setcookie('remember', '1', time() + (10 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/');
setcookie("sesion", true, time() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/", "", false, true);
```

He intentado de todo, e incluso poniendo estas lineas de codigo en mi HTML, sigue sin ser solucionado.

```html
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

A su vez, he comprobado con la consola del navegador que la cookie esté correctamente configurada y lo está, pero incluso así el código no es funcional. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Y verificaste que la cookie si este guardada en el navegador?

Comment: Así es. He comprobado con la consola del navegador que la cookie esté correctamente configurada y lo está.

Comment: Tu problema es que agregaste 2 parámetros más innecesarios, intenta cambiar *setcookie("sesion", true, time() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/", "", false, true);* por *setcookie("sesion", true, time() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/", "");* y nos comentas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para solucionar el Problema debes quitar los últimos 2 parámetros de tu *setcookie*

Cambia

```
setcookie("sesion", true, time() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/", "", false, true);
```

Por

```
setcookie("sesion", true, time() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/", "");
```

Esto pasa porque los últimos 2 son para que solo sea en HTTPS y el otro para validar que justo no se pueda leer en Javascript, puedes verificar directamente en la documentación de PHP :

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php

En la sección de **secure** y **httponly** (esta última es la que bloquea en JS como te comenté anteriormente).

Comment: Muchas gracias! Funcionó